# Loading handsontable with local data fails

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am trying to use http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/y66uc1cq/ to load some data which I have included into a handsontable view. Although the JS is valid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getCarData() {
        return [
        ["Nissan", 2009, "black", "black"], ["Nissan", 2006, "blue", "blue"], ["Chrysler", 2004, "yellow", "black"], ["Volvo", 2012, "white", "gray"]];
    }

    var data = [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];




    $("#example1").handsontable({
        data: data,
        minRows: 5,
        minCols: 6,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
        currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
        autoWrapRow: true,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true
    });


    $("#example1").handsontable('selectCell', 3, 3);





});
```

The load is not occurring. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't even have jQuery, let alone the handsontable plugin (that's a plugin right?).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to test since all the references in the fiddle are broken, but try this:

```
var table = new Handsontable($("#example1"), {
    data: data,
    minRows: 5,
    minCols: 6,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
    autoWrapRow: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true
});
table.render();
```

Source: http://handsontable.com/demo/understanding_reference.html

Comment: Hi Brent, I couldn't get it working but your reference helped me. Thank you.